# fill-paragraph on multiple paragraphs at once

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph, paragraphs

I often cut and paste non "filled" text into text files (mostly in org-mode).  I then have to go line by line and call `fill-paragraph` or `org-fill-paragraph` in org-mode to clean up the text.  I was wondering if there's a way to apply this operation to multiple paragraphs at once maybe in a region.  For example, if we have the following paragraphs in org-mode with fill-column set to 20:

```
- This is the first paragraph.
- This is the second paragraph.
```

I'd like to mark both with a region, and then have them transform into:

```
- This is the first
  paragraph.
- This is the second
  paragraph.
```

It seems that `fill-region` is suppose to do this.  I've tried calling it with various parameter combinations but it just condenses that entire region as one paragraph:

```
- This is the first
paragraph. - This
is the second
paragraph.
```

Comment: This sounds like `fill-forward-paragraph-function` is not being set up correctly by org-mode. You should take this up with the org-mode developers.

Comment: This works for me in org-mode 9.3 with emacs option -Q. Pasting long line text in list items into a new org-mode buffer and `C-x h M-q`.

Comment: How can I fix `fill-forward-paragraph-function`?

Comment: Works fine for me:  Org mode version 9.5.3 (release_9.5.3-526-g548632). Try with emacs -q?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about Org mode, but in normal circumstances those two lines are not considered paragraphs, because they are separated only by a single newline character (`C-j`).

However, if you separate them by a blank line (i.e., another newline char), then `M-x fill-region` does what you expect:

```
- This is the first paragraph.

- This is the second paragraph.
```

becomes (assuming `fill-column` is 20):

```
- This is the first
  paragraph.

- This is the second
  paragraph.
```

See the Emacs manual, node [Paragaphs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Paragraphs.html), and the Elisp manual, node [Standard Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Regexps.html).  See, in particular, option `paragraph-separate`.

Comment: org-mode sets paragraph-separate correctly so that they are considered as separate paragraphs. It's just that it doesn't do the right thing with `fill-forward-paragraph-function`